# how to define the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by a given equation

Tags: limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

> Define functions $f ( x )$ and $g ( x )$ by
>   $f ( x ) = \frac { \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } - 2 } { x - 8 } , \quad g ( x ) = \frac { 1 } { \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } ^ { 2 } + 2 \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } + 4 }$
>
> (a) By multiplying $f ( x )$ by
>   $$\frac { \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } ^ { 2 } + 2 \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } + 4 } { \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } ^ { 2 } + 2 \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } + 4 }$$
>   show that $f ( x ) = g ( x )$ for all real numbers $x \neq 2$
>
> (b) Using the Equal Limit Theorem from lectures, find
>   $$\lim _ { x \rightarrow 8 } \frac { \sqrt [ 3 ] { x } - 2 } { x - 8 }$$

The question is in the link provided. For (a), I solved $f(x)=g(x)$ by using a value that gives a whole number when cube rooted. So I subbed in 64 for x because cube root 64 is 4. After solving, I got $\frac{1}{28}$ for both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. But I'm not sure how to solve (b) using the equal limit theorem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should be x not equal to 8 (not 2).

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Should not you just plug in 8 in g
(x)? This gives 1/12.

Answer (score 1):

For a you need to show it holds for all $x$ except $2$, not for one specific $x$.  It sounds like you just showed it for $x=64$.  You are expected to carry out the multiplication suggested and manipulate it to get $g(x)$.

For b the point is that $g(x)$ does not have an indeterminate $\frac 00$ at $x=8$.  As it is continuous you can just substitute in $x=8$ to find the limit.

The fraction you are supposed to multiply by was found by looking at $x-8$ as $(\sqrt[3]x)^3-8$, which is a difference of cubes and using the standard factorization.

Answer (score 0):

For part b)

I looked up "equal limit theorem" and didn't really find anything on this.

If you try and evaluate the limit algebraically it doesn't really work out, however you can use L Hopitals rule on it.

The limit ends up being 1/4

Comment: equal limit theorem just says lim x->a f(x) = lim x->a g(x)

Comment: So what that means is that you need to take the limit of f(x) and g(x) and show that both of them are equal. From part (a) we know that f(x) and g(x) are related.

Comment: for a this is what I have so far: ((cube root x)-2 / x-8) x ((cube root x)+2)^2 / ((cube root x)+2)^2. how would i proceed from here?